# solving wave equation in polar

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve the wave equation under polar coordinates.This is my code:

```
NDSolveValue[
  {
    (Derivative[0,2,0][ϕ][r,θ,t]/r
     + Derivative[1,0,0][ϕ][r,θ,t])/r
     + Derivative[2,0,0][ϕ][r,θ,t]
     == Derivative[0,0,2][ϕ][r,θ,t],
    ϕ[10,θ,t] == 0,
    Derivative[0,0,1][ϕ][r,θ,0] == 0,
    ϕ[r,θ,0] == Exp[-5*r^2]
  },
  ϕ[r,θ,t],
  {r,0,10},
  {θ,0,2*Pi},
  {t,0,50}
]
```

But this is returning error that infinite expression 1/0 encountered.What is the way out?

Comment: Actually the mathematica code got this form after copy pasting,i dont know how to change it to that form.

Comment: What did you expect to happen at $r=0$? If you ask for a solution for $2\leq r\leq 10$, you get some more useful warning and solutions

Comment: And regarding the formatting of the code: In this case, `InputForm[Hold[…]]` gives you something that is more readable as plain text

Comment: I'm missing boundary conditions here. What's supposed to happen at `r = 0`? Where is the periodic boundary condition for `theta`? Also, strictly speaking your initial condition is in conflict with your BC at `r==10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a work around. I am not sure why it fails in polar, but changing the PDE to use Cartesian coordinates works.

[image]

```
ClearAll[x, y, r, t];
region = Disk[{0, 0}, 10];
r = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
pde = D[u[x, y, t], {t, 2}] == Laplacian[u[x, y, t], {x, y}];
ic  = {u[x, y, 0] == Exp[-5*r^2], Derivative[0, 0, 1][u][x, y, 0] == 0};
bc  = DirichletCondition[u[x, y, t] == 0, r == 10];

solM2 = NDSolveValue[{pde, bc, ic}, u, {t, 0, 5}, Element[{x, y}, region]];
```

The animation code is

```
framesNDSolveM2 = Table[
   Grid[{{Row[{"time = ", t}]},
     {Plot3D[solM2[x, y, t],
       Element[{x, y}, solM2["ElementMesh"]],
       PlotRange -> {-0.5, 0.5},
       Boxed -> True, Axes -> True,
       Mesh -> 20,
       ImageSize -> 300,
       ViewPoint -> {2.17, -2.4, 1},
       BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
      }}
    ], {t, 0, 5, .01}];
```

Now

```
Manipulate[
 framesNDSolveM2[[i]],
 {{i, 1, "time"}, 1, Length[framesNDSolveM2], 1}
 ]
```